# Prove that vector space V isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$, explicit isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Someone asked me this as a help for their linear algebra homework but I couldn't figure it out.

Let $V=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}: y>0\}$. It is a vector space under the operations

$$(x_1, y_1) \oplus (x_2, y_2)=(x_1+x_2+1, y_1 y_2)$$

and

$$\lambda \odot(x,y)=(\lambda x+\lambda -1, y^\lambda )$$

And it is required to prove that V is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the usual vector operations. I tried to solve it finding a base and using dimension but the student said that his teacher have not yet defined dimension (which seems odd to me but ok) and that an explicit linear isomorphism shouldn't be hard to find.

Thank you.

Comment: The isomorphism is not linear.  The fact that you have multiplication of the $y$s where addition belongs should suggest logs/exponentiation.  First look for the equivalent of the zero vector.

Comment: Yes, I also thought that It shouldn't be linear and found the zero vector (-1,1), but there I got confused, if there isn't a linear isomorphism, can they be isomorphic as vector spaces?. I tried two or three different functions but the linearity being different things in each space made my attemtps fail.

Comment: Yes.  You just need a bijective $f:V \leftrightarrow \Bbb R^2$ so that $f(v \oplus w)=f(v)+f(w)$ and $\lambda \odot f(v)=f(\lambda v)$

Comment: It might perhaps help that every $(x, y) \in V$ can be written as $(x, 1) \oplus (-1, y)$. I'm not entirely sure on this, but I feel like any explicit isomorphism you could write down will require you to make a certain choice (a base $b > 0$ for your logarithms), of course easiest would be to just take $e$ as a base and work with natural logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is already proved that $V$ is a vector space under these operations, then it's enough to specify an isomorphism. We have
\begin{align*}
x\odot (0,1)\oplus y\odot (1,2)
&= (x-1,1)\oplus (2y-1,2^y)\\
&= (x+2y-1,2^y).
\end{align*}
The zero vector in $V$ is $(-1,1)$. Hence, only the trivial linear combination of $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ equals the zero vector, meaning that these two vectors are linearly independent in $V$. So, the linear map $f : \mathbb R^2\to V$, defined by $f(1,0) = (0,1)$ and $f(0,1) = (1,2)$, is an isomorphism. We have
$$
f(x,y) = x\odot f(1,0) \oplus y\odot f(0,1) = (x+2y-1,2^y).
$$